# Thinkpad fingerprint scan only at login

Tags: command-line, login, thinkpad, lenovo, fingerprint-reader

I know how to set up the fingerprint reader for my Thinkpad X220 in Ubuntu 11.10.

My question is: Is it possible to only use the fingerprint reader at the LightDM-Login and not when typing "sudo ..." in the terminal or starting an application that needs superuser rights?

Comment: What do you want to use for authentication for `sudo` and others? Password, something else, or nothing? The first two require changes to `/etc/pam.d/sudo`, the last to `/etc/sudoers`. Could you show contents of the relevant file in your system?

Comment: I would like to use password authentication all the time except at LightDM login.
My `/etc/pam.d/sudo`:
`#%PAM-1.0

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive`

My `/etc/sudoers`:
`Defaults env_reset
Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# User privilege specification
root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

Comment: Sorry, my post again, more readable:

I would like to use password authentication all the time except at LightDM login.
My `/etc/pam.d/sudo`: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/922617/)
My `/etc/sudoers`: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/922622/)

Answer (score 2):

This solution assumes that you only have (or had) to modify `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` to make fingerprint reader work.

- Make a copy of the file `sudo cp -p /etc/pam.d/common-auth /etc/pam.d/common-auth-finger` and make the necessary changes to that file instead (if you use `pam-auth-update` or some other automated tool, just let it make changes, and swap the files afterwards)
- In `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` replace the line that has `@include common-auth` to read `@include common-auth-finger`

This should be all that is needed. If you had changed pam configuration in a different way, please tell how.