# disable fingerprint authentication at login

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, lightdm, authentication, fingerprint-reader

I have installed fingerprint-GUI using:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui
```

But it also accepts fingerprint authentication at login (lightdm). I only want it with sudo, gksudo, and su, i.e, after I've logged in, it should then accept fingerprints.

I'm on Xubuntu 16.04 AMD64, up to date. And my machine is a ThinkPad T410

**EDIT:**
this is my `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` file's contents:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup nopasswdlogin
@include common-auth
auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
auth    optional        pam_kwallet.so
auth    optional        pam_kwallet5.so
@include common-account
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so close
#session required        pam_loginuid.so
session required        pam_limits.so
@include common-session
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so open
session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
session optional        pam_kwallet.so auto_start
session optional        pam_kwallet5.so auto_start
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
@include common-password
```

And the common-auth:

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-auth - authentication settings common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of the authentication modules that define
# the central authentication scheme for use on the system
# (e.g., /etc/shadow, LDAP, Kerberos, etc.).  The default is to use the
# traditional Unix authentication mechanisms.
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_fingerprint-gui.so try_first_identified debug
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` file? I found an answer that is asking something similar, but the inverse. It's basically asking for a way to enable fingerprint for everything but the login on `lightdm`. Here's the [answer link](https://askubuntu.com/a/120921/602680). The same concept could be used in this case.

Comment: @OwenHines I've added the contents to the answer.

Comment: Could you also post `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`? Sorry I didn't mention it in the first comment.

Comment: @OwenHines added common-auth's contents too.

Comment: @TheOdd Could you please persist what next?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thinkpad fingerprint scan only at login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82624/thinkpad-fingerprint-scan-only-at-login)

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to disable it via GUI. Search Users and mark Fingerprint login as "disabled".

Comment: I couldn't find an option like that.

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/enable-fingerprint-ubuntu-800x607.png