# Enabling fingerprint login in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, login, laptop, 21.10, fingerprint-reader

I have looked around and found that Ubuntu supports fingerprint reading, but I can't find any information for Xubuntu. I have tried to find the equivalent of *Settings → Users → Authentication & Login*, but I haven't had any luck.

How can I enable my laptop's fingerprint reader in Xubuntu 21.10?

My laptop is an HP ProBook 650 G2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [disable fingerprint authentication at login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966469/disable-fingerprint-authentication-at-login)

Comment: @digiwizkid Fingerprint-gui won't install. It only works for very old versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't know whether XFCE supports fingerprint login yet. However, according to [this](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=ed75de89e3), the kernel does not support the driver (so, it may not work in even GNOME or KDE, which support fingerprint login), and the driver is available at https://github.com/rindeal/libfprint-vfs_proprietary-driver

Comment: If it is a Synaptics fingerprintreader (like mine, HP ENVY 17Ce1000) it is not supported by the kernel. Synaptics and HP don't make drivers for Linux-based systems.

Answer (score 4):

This probably wont be a solution to the question but it might be help someone like me who got there multiple times trying to solve similar issue.

I managed to get finger print working on Samsung 400B laptop with Linux Mint Xfse using [`fprintd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/).
First  probably is worth to check [supported device list](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html). My one was listed there.

```
Device-3: 2-1.5:4 info: AuthenTec type: <vendor specific> driver: N/A rev: 2.0 chip ID: 08ff:168a
```

(In Mint you can find it under "System Reports" > "System information")

Installation:

```bash
apt-get install fprintd libpam-fprintd
```

Then add enroll (register) your finger print:

```bash
fprintd-enroll <USERNAME>
```

you should be asked to swipe your finger (note what you need to do that multiple times)

To verify fingerprint:

```bash
fprintd-verify <USERNAME>
```

Then what I needed to do is to modify `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` and add this line:

```
auth sufficient pam_fprintd.so
```

I try few places to put it at. I noticed if I add it as last command it asked for password and then I needed to verify with fingerprint as well. That can be useful for extra security, but that not was my goal. So I added it to the beginning:

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth sufficient pam_fprintd.so
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
```

and that gave me finger-print first and if it succeeds then I'm in, but if it fails 3 times then I can enter password to authenticate.

Informative article on PAM file [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pam-to-configure-authentication-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried fprintd, it is working well with my hp pavalion dv4-1502tu notebook. I am running zorin os Lite.

But make sure your device should be listed [here](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html)

To check your fingerprint reader details run below command in terminal

`lsusb | grep Finger`

Sample output is like below

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID **138a:0001** Validity Sensors, Inc. **VFS101** Fingerprint Reader
```